# What's the Purpose of Park on an Automatic Transmission?

Tags: automatic-transmission

When one wants to park a manual transmission (MTX) vehicle, one puts it in neutral, and engages the emergency / parking brake.  With an ATX vehicle, the practice I've learned is to put it in Park, **and** engage the parking brake.

But if I need to engage the parking brake, then what exactly is the purpose of selecting Park?  What does selecting Park do and how does it differ from selecting neutral?

Comment: It may be different in countries that still sell a good number of manuals, but here in the states, I've never met anyone that puts an automatic in park and sets the brake unless they're on an extreme hill.

Comment: @JPhi1618  I park with the transmission in park and pull the brake every time. Belts and braces: I really don't want the car moving at all until I'm ready.

Comment: @BobCross What I do is; Put it in neutral first and pull the hand brake. Then take your foot off the brake. After that I that I put in it park. Is this better than just putting it in park and pulling the hand brake?

Comment: Umm, I put my manual transmission into gear when parking, not neutral.

Comment: Like @Ellesedil said, you don't want to park in neutral.  In general you want the lowest gear available in your transmission to maximize the engine breaking.  Some cars (looking at you Saab) won't even let you take the keys out of a manual transmission unless it is in reverse.  I learned in a Saab and still put everything into reverse since it is usually geared lower then 1st.

Comment: @Ellesedil on a hill the lowest uphill gear is a good idea and what I do.  On the flat it seems excessive. If all drivers of the car *always* leave it in gear it's fine, but you need to remember to take it out of gear when starting.  Checking it's not in gear before turning on is of course a good idea but sometimes neglected in a hurry (and some people never check).

Comment: @Ukko I drove a Saab once, years ago, and it had a few oddities like that -- do they also have an interlock to make sure you take it out of reverse before turning on?

Comment: @ChrisH everyone I've spoken with (in a country where manuals are the norm) do what I do, which is to always start the car with the clutch depressed. If you make **that** the habit, rather than relying on the behavior of the previous driver, it doesn't matter what gear whoever drove the car last leaves it in.

Comment: @Alex, that's my habit too, but again, it's not universal.  It's more common in people whose habits were formed in slightly rubbish cars or those with manual chokes.

Comment: In my country, Automatic is extremely Rare, 90% of the population drives Manual and when i first saw the PNRD thing i was wondering about the same.. Good question

Comment: @Alex: for contrast, in my country (where manuals are at least 95% of the market) no one I know presses the clutch to start.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, and for further contrast, both manual transmission cars I have owned (2002 Kia and 1988 Toyota) wouldn't start the engine *at all* unless the clutch was pressed.  So there you go.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In an automatic transmission there is a ring with teeth on the output shaft of the transmission. When the transmission is shifted into park a lever called the parking pawl is lowered against the ring. If the parking pawl did not land squarely into an opening in the ring the car will roll slightly and there will be a usually an audible click. The parking pawl now holds the output shaft from turning.

[image: Automatic transmission showing parking pawl]

Without the engine running an automatic transmission is effectively in neutral in any gear except park. Theoretically with park engaged also applying the parking brake is not necessary unless the car is on a big hill because the parking pawl has more than enough strength to hold the car from rolling. It is a good idea to exercise the parking brake on a car with an automatic so the system does not freeze up.

PS. In a manual it is suggested to place the car in first gear or reverse then engage the parking brake and for good measure curb the wheels. In the event that the parking brake fails (more common than the parking paw) the engine with the sub one gear ratio will hold the car. The good measure of curbing the wheels will roll the car into the curb in the case that the engine can't hold the car from rolling.

Comment: Love that picture - thanks.  The pic can also be interpreted as: This little piece of metal is the only thing holding your 4000lb car in place.

Comment: What vehicle is this chain-driven transmission from?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma - The image appears to be a screencap from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eh988eSAPc8).  At 0:40, he says it's a FWD Ford 6F35, so there are [several vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GM-Ford_6-speed_automatic_transmission) it could be from, though he says it's from a Ford Escape in the comments.

Comment: If you accidentally put the trans in Park while rolling, the pawl will not engage, it just makes a lot of racket and you go "*Doh!*" I did this once when I saw my brother's car ahead of me get hit by another car. I was so startled I got confused and didn't stop correctly.

Comment: @user15009 Maybe. Sometimes (if you're going slow enough?) it will still engage and will stop your vehicle abruptly, perhaps damaging the transmission in the process.

Comment: Thank you, finally I understand where the "thunk" sound came from, nice picture, a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: (+) great explanation. If the vehicle was not designed for drifting purposes, what if hand break is switched on instead of this mechanism when one outs the gear into P? There would be no need for an extra hand break thing; also using P without hand break switched on, this mechanism seems dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

When you engage Park but do not engage the parking brake, the weight of the car is held by only the little parking pawl lever inside the transfer case, as opposed to the car's actual parking brake. When you start your engine the next time, you can feel an unpleasant "thunk" when you move the selector out of Park, if there was even a tiny unevenness to the pavement. This is because the little parking pawl is literally FORCED out of the lock, overcoming the weight of the car. It is always recommended to engage the parking brake first, to let car's weight rest on the brake, before moving the selector into Park. That way, the next time you start the engine and move the selector out of Park, there is no more "thunk" because the weight of the car is held by the parking brake, not by the little parking pawl. (Unless you release the parking brake first, without holding the brake pedal, before moving the selector into Park. In that case, you would actually feel the car move a little, its weight falling back onto the engaged parking pawl.)

After arriving, recommended to 
1. Engage parking brake.
2. Move selector into Park.
3. Let go of the brake pedal.
4. Stop engine.

Before leaving, recommended to
1. Press the brake pedal.
2. Start engine.
3. Move selector into Drive (or Reverse).
4. Release parking brake.

There will never be that rough "thunk" moving out of Park when these steps are followed, because the car's weight will not rest on the parking pawl that locks the output shaft.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! So your reasoning is... because there is a "thunk" sound, you should do whatever it takes to avoid that sound? And what makes you think the "thunk" sound is so bad?

Comment: It's not the sound itself that is the problem. The problem is what's creating that sound. Needless wear and tear on the parking pawl and gear that it engages into. The parking brake is designed to bear the weight of the car, especially if the surface is sloped or uneven. The little parking pawl inside the transfer case is only designed to lock the output shaft, because leaving an automatic in D, R, 1, 2, etc., with the engine off, the output shaft can still freely rotate, because the torque converter is not sending any torque. With the parking brake engaged, no forced "thunk" coming out of P.

Answer (score 1):

The ideas behind this article are sound, but perhaps not always explained the best way, which may be why some posters haven't understood it!
When stopping in an auto, the correct procedure is:- Stop with the footbrake, engage handbrake (parking brake), select neutral, release footbrake (it's this that allows the car to "settle" and thus not apply subsequent pressure on the pawl), re-apply footbrake, engage park, release footbrake, switch off.
The "thunk" isn't the problem, it's the wear and tear indicated by the "thunk" that's the problem.