# Proper parking technique for a car with electronic parking brake

Tags: parking, parking-brake

I have got my first car, a 14' Audi S4 that is equipped with an electronic parking brake.

My common sense told me to park as following:

1. Come to a complete stop
2. Engage electronic parking brake
3. Put car in Parking gear
4. Release brake pedal

By doing this, I believed I could ensure that if there is any slope, the car weight pressure will be on the parking brake and not on my transmission/gears (please excuse my illiteracy in terms of car functioning as this is purely based on what I believe is happening)

Now, what I see 10/10 times when I have my car serviced with my local Audi dealer, not a single time was it parked with use of the parking brake. I can imagine that the common assumption is "use parking brake only when parking on steep hills". So, when I pick up my car and try putting it into drive, many times I hear a hard clunk sound when I move the shifter. I imagine this cannot be good for the transmission.

So finally, my question: is my procedure preferred/required? Or I am I just thinking too much and it is unnecessary?

Comment: I am just asking for curiosity. Does the e-brakes auto-activates when you shift to P? Or the car has a button to activate the e-brake?

Comment: The car has a button to activate it. It can only turn off by itself when you put into drive but does not engage when you park.

Comment: Related: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/25626/12030, maybe a duplicate, but not sure enough to vote as a dupe.

Comment: I don't think you should take the mechanic's practice as a recommendation.  I have a standard transmission car with an ordinary mechanical parking brake, and my mechanics for some reason never use the parking brake when parking it, which I'm pretty confident is unwise.  Luckily their parking lot is pretty flat, and they do at least leave it in gear, and it'll be their insurance on the hook if it rolls away.